# Asymptotics of $\vartheta(x+y)-\vartheta(x)$, where $\vartheta$ is the Chebyshev function, when $y\in[x^\alpha, x]$ for some $\alpha\in(0,1)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics

#### Introduction

Consider $\vartheta$ to be the Chebyshev function, that is, $\vartheta(x)$ denotes, for $x\in\mathbb N$, the sum $\sum_{p\le x,\ p\text{ prime}} \ln p$.

I am interested in asymptotics for $$\vartheta(x+y)-\vartheta(x)$$ as $x,y\to\infty$, where we assume that $y$ is smaller than $x$, but larger than some power of $x$, that is, $y\in[x^\alpha, x]$ for some $\alpha\in(0,1)$. (This latter relation between $x,y$ and $x\to\infty$ will be assumed implicitly during the rest of the post.)

More specifically, I would like to know about results which show that

\begin{equation}\label{eq:main}\tag{1}\vartheta(x+y)-\vartheta(y)=y+O\left(\frac{y}{(\ln x)^A}\right)\end{equation}
for some $A>0$.

I found a result in the literature which establishes \eqref{eq:main} for $\alpha>\frac{7}{12}$ and $A=\frac 1{44}$ (see the "advanced estimates" section below), and would like to inquire about results which sharpen this result, either by lowering $\alpha$, or by increasing $A$.

#### Naive estimates

It is known [1] that $$\vartheta(x) = x + O\left(\frac x{(\ln x)^4}\right),$$ from which one can deduce
\begin{equation}\vartheta(x+y)-\vartheta(y) = y + O\left(\frac{x}{(\ln x)^4}\right).\label{eq:insufficient}\tag{2}\end{equation}

However, this is not very satisfying, as I would like to achieve an error term of the form $$O\left(\frac{y}{(\ln x)^A}\right)$$ for some $A>0$. Since $y$ can be of order $x^\alpha$ for $\alpha\in(0,1)$, it follows that \eqref{eq:insufficient} is insufficient.

#### Naive estimates under Riemann hypothesis

Under the Riemann hypothesis, we have [2]
$$\vartheta(x)=x+O\left(\sqrt x (\ln x)^2\right),$$
from which we get
$$\vartheta(x+y)-\vartheta(x) = y + O\left(\sqrt x (\ln x)^2\right).$$
The result is satisfying, as we get \eqref{eq:main} for $\alpha>\frac 12$ and any $A>0$.

However, it is unsatisfying that we need to assume the Riemann hypothesis.

#### Advanced estimates

Consider the prime counting function $\pi$, so that $\pi(z)$ denotes the number of prime numbers $p$ satisfying $p\le z$ for $z\in\mathbb R$.

We then have $$\vartheta(x+y)-\vartheta(x) = \left(\ln x+O\left(\frac yx\right)\right) (\pi(x+y)-\pi(x)).$$

Heath-Brown [3] has obtained
$$\pi(x)-\pi(x-y) = \frac{y}{\ln x} + O\left(y (\ln x)^{-\frac{45}{44}}\right)$$
whenever $x^{\frac 7{12}}\le y\le x$.

Therefore, by replacing $x$ with $x+y$, this establishes \eqref{eq:main} for $\alpha>\frac{7}{12}$ and $A=\frac 1{44}$.

#### Advanced estimates which I didn't get to work

Heath-Brown [4] has established
$$\pi(x)-\pi(x-y)=\frac{y}{\ln x}\left(1+O\left(\left(\frac{\ln \ln x}{\ln x}\right)^4\right)\right)$$
for $x^{\frac 7{12}}\le y\le\frac{x}{(\ln x)^4}$, which, by replacing $x$ with $x+y$, translastes straightforwardly to an analogous statement for $\pi(x+y)-\pi(x)$.

However, **I don't know what happens when $\frac{x}{(\ln x)^4}<y\le x$...**

#### References

[1] Pierre Dusart, *Sharper bounds for $\psi, \theta,\pi, p_k$*. Rapport de recherche n° 1998-06.
[2] Helge von Koch, *Sur la distribution des nombres premiers*, Acta Math. v. 24, pages. 159-182, 1901.
[3] David Rodney Heath-Brown, *Sieve identities and gaps between primes*. Astérisque, tome 94, pages 61-65, 1982.
[4] David Rodney Heath-Brown, *The number of primes in a short interval*. Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik 389, pages 22-63, 1998.

#### Related questions

- [Best available bounds for $\pi(Y)-\pi(Y-X)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/433551/129831)

Comment: I think if you really want an asymptotic then Heath-Brown's result is the best there is. If you are happy with a lower bound on $\vartheta(x + y) - \vartheta(x)$ of the right order of magnitude then many people (Heath-Brown, Iwaniec, Baker, ...) have worked on this problem, and the best result is due to Baker--Harman--Pintz from 2001, where they showed that $\alpha = 0.525$ works.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/frequently-asked-questions-about-tagging-on-mathoverflow

Comment: A complete aside by the way: if Heath-Brown wanted to be cited with his full name, he probably wouldn't use initials for the majority (all?) his papers. I think it's usually best to defer to the name format that actually appears in the publication when citing.

Comment: @AnuragSahay Thank you for the pointer towards Baker--Harman--Pintz! I am interested in asymptotics, so I guess stopping at Heath-Brown is all I can do. Also thanks for your second comment, in principle I agree with you, but I think it is not very important if we write out the initials or not.